# iOS left slide navigation mernu

Tags: ios

I want to have in my app some nice slide navigationmanu just like in [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). My problem is that SWRevealViewController needs iOS 7.0 and ARC and in my project I have iOS 6.0 without ARC. Is there any way to use SWRevealViewController in my app or maybe there is any alternative to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell about SWRevealViewController without ARC or iOS7 (thus I cannot directly answer your question), but I would put a lot of weight behind the following :

Over 80% of all iOS devices currently run iOS7 or greater. ARC has been available since iOS5, which is several years ago.

The mobile market is a quickly evolving one. Not upgrading will quickly lead you to a dark path where you'll end up fighting a losing battle. I understand that your project probably has limitations, but converting right now and keeping up with new technologies will save you a lot of trouble (for instance, trying to make a newer component work with your specific setup).

I would add, the same goes for AutoLayout. If you aren't using it already, you should start, NOW. Rumor has it the next iPhones will vary in size, and the legacy way of handling visuals cannot scale correctly (perhaps the whole reason AutoLayout was created is to prepare this change).

So in short, I wouldn't recommend adapting a new component to your old project, but rather updating your old project to make it modern. You'll end up saving a lot of time.

Comment: I know and if this decision was mine I would do this without any doubt, but I cant decide about that :(

Comment: I feared that would be the case. At least, you could try to make the point to whoever holds the power to decide. This way, you earn the right to a "told you so".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at ViewDeck https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

It is compatible with iOS 6 and non-ARC.